# How does this line of VB.NET code work?

Tags: vb.net, string.format

I am using VB.NET and String.Format.

The line of code below populates s with 20 space characters. The problem is that I don't know how it works and can't find an explanation. Reference: [MSDN String.Format Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Format(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Dim s As String = String.Format("{0, 20}", String.Empty)
```

It gives me the result I need, a string populated with with 20 space characters, but what is the "0"?  If I change that to any other num it creates an error.

And I don't see where / how it's specifying a Space char?

Comment: Perhaps the best explanation is here [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Suzy In [the mentioned page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Format(v=vs.110).aspx#FormatItem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format specififer `{0, 20}` indicates that it will place your object `string.Empty` as element `{0}` at the end of an empty 20 character string. By that I mean that your item will be used to fill the right side of a 20 character string and the remainder will be padded. Since you're using `string.Empty` you get a completely blank string. Try adding z and changing the number to a negative number.

```
string.Format("{0, -10}", "z");
```

This should give you a 10 character string starting with z and filled with spaces. This is default behavior for `string.Format`, and it is most commonly used when formatting custom numerics. The space doesn't need to be included as part of the command because that's considered expected by the fact that your specifier indicated you wanted a result string of 20 characters. Space seems the most logical inserted default character.

If you use a complex string like:

```
string.Format("{0, 10}", "abc");
```

You should still get a 10 character string but it will look like

```
"       abc"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `0` in the first parameter is the index of the argument.

The signature of that method is `String.Format(string format, object[] params)`.

So `"{0, 20}"` is the string to be formatted, and everything else is turned into an object array.

Answer (score 1):

the zero is the index of the parameter that you are sending, in your case `String.Empty`